# Removing a character from a string

Tags: python

I am asked the following:

```
def myRemove( str, ch ):
 # Return a new string with the first occurrence of ch removed.  If there is none, return str.
```

Sample run

```
>>> myRemove( "abcdabcd", "a")
'bcdabcd'
>>> myRemove( "abcdabcd", "x")
'abcdabcd'
>>> myRemove( "abcdabcd", "d")
'abcabcd'
```

I have tried a few different methods but have not been able to figure the problem out. Here is my attempt:

```
def myRemove( str, ch ):
    for num in range (0, len(str)):
        if (str[num] == ch):
            return str[0:num] + str[num + 1:]
        else:
            return str
```

There is also an extension to this problem which asks : `Return a new string with all occurrences of ch removed. If there are none, return str.` However, since I have not been able to solve the first part, naturally I was not sure how to solve the second. Would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: This is a question about elementary programming, which is not quite on-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the loop will only occur once! In the beginning `num` will be 0. At this point, we enter the `if` statement:

- if we got that `str[0] == ch` (notice that `num==0` and thus `str[0]==str[num]`), then we return some string
- otherwise we return another string

The important thing here, is that no matter what - we will quit in the first iteration of the `for` loop.

To fix this, consider placing the `return str` outside the `for` loop (without `else` as well)

Comment: Is it possible for me to make simple modifications which return a new string with all occurrences of ch removed? Or should I should I try to create a while loop?

Comment: There is a (quite simple) modification you can do. Try to think how not to stop only at the first character you see.